# Merge many tab seprated files based on first column

Tags: bash, awk

I have many TSV files in a directory that have only three columns, I want to merge all of them based on the first column value (both columns have headers that I need to maintain); if this value is present then it must add the value of the corresponding second and third column, and if value missing in any file add NA and so on (see example). Files might have different number of lines and not ordered by first column, although this can be easily done with sort.

I have tried join but that works nicely for only two files. Can join be expanded for all files in a directory?  Here are the example of just three files:

```
S01.tsv

Accesion    Val S01 
AJ863320    1  0.2
AM930424    1  0.3
AY664038    2  0.5

S02.tsv

Accesion    Val S02
AJ863320    2  0.8
AM930424    1  0.25
EU236327    1  0.14
EU434346    2  0.2

S03.tsv

Accesion    Val S03
AJ863320    5  0.2
EU236327    1  0.5
EU434346    2  0.3
```

Outfile should be:

```
    Accesion   Val   S01   S02   S03  
    AJ863320   1   0.2   NA   NA
    AJ863320   2   NA   0.8   NA
    AJ863320   5   NA   NA    0.2
    AM930424   1   0.3  0.25  NA
    AY664038   2   0.5  NA    NA
    EU236327   1   NA   0.14  0.5    
    EU434346   2   NA   0.2  0.3
```

Ok I've tried with awk by taking help here, but not successful

```
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }                            # tab separated columns
FNR==1 { f++ }                                # counter of files
{
    a[0][$1]=$1                               # reset the key for every record 
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                        # for each non-key element
        a[f][$1]=a[f][$1] $i ( i==NF?"":OFS ) # combine them to array element
}
END {                                         # in the end
    for(i in a[0])                            # go thru every key
        for(j=0;j<=f;j++)                     # and all related array elements
            printf "%s%s", a[j][i], (j==f?ORS:OFS)
}                                             # output them, nonexistent will output empty
```

Comment: In your example, you have different column names for files 1,2 and 3 (`S01`..`S03`). Is this just to illustrate different content, or will each of the files actually have different column names ?  What I mean, can you generally say "3rd column" (`S`) is the value for that file ?

Comment: @MyICQ Yes each file have different 3rd column name! Thank you for your effort!!

Comment: Regarding `FNR==1 { f++ }` - you're using GNU awk for arrays of arrays so you don't need to do that as GNU awk has a builtin variable `ARGIND` to do what you're using `f` for. Regarding `a[0][$1]=$1` - awk field numbers, char positions in strings, and generated arrays all start at 1, not 0, so don't create your own arrays that start at 0 to avoid tripping over that difference in other parts of your code. "Everything starts at 1" is a simpler rule to remember than having to remember which arrays start at 0 while everything else starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `S01.tsv` content be

```
Accesion    Val S01 
AJ863320    1  0.2
AM930424    1  0.3
AY664038    2  0.5
```

and `S02.tsv` content be

```
Accesion    Val S02
AJ863320    2  0.8
AM930424    1  0.25
EU236327    1  0.14
EU434346    2  0.2
```

and `S03.tsv` content be

```
Accesion    Val S03
AJ863320    5  0.2
EU236327    1  0.5
EU434346    2  0.3
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==1{title=$1 OFS $2}{arr[$1 OFS $2][FILENAME]=$3}END{print title,arr[title]["S01.tsv"],arr[title]["S02.tsv"],arr[title]["S03.tsv"];delete arr[title];for(i in arr){print i,"S01.tsv" in arr[i]?arr[i]["S01.tsv"]:"NA","S02.tsv" in arr[i]?arr[i]["S02.tsv"]:"NA","S03.tsv" in arr[i]?arr[i]["S03.tsv"]:"NA"}}' S01.tsv S02.tsv S03.tsv
```

gives output

```
Accesion    Val S01 S02 S03
AJ863320    1   0.2 NA  NA
AJ863320    2   NA  0.8 NA
AJ863320    5   NA  NA  0.2
EU236327    1   NA  0.14    0.5
AM930424    1   0.3 0.25    NA
EU434346    2   NA  0.2 0.3
AY664038    2   0.5 NA  NA
```

Explanation: I am storing data in 2D array `arr`, using values from 1st and 2nd column concatenated using output field separator (first dimension) and filename (2nd dimensions). Values in array are values from 3rd column. After data is collected I started by `print`ing title (header) row, which I then `delete` from array, then I iterate over first dimension of array, and for each element I `print` key followed by values from each file or `NA` if there was not value. Observe that I use `in` check rather than looking for truthiness of value itself as this would alter `0` values into `NA`s. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes you are accepting any order of output rows beyond headers, if this does not hold do not use this solution.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Just a, hopefully, helpful suggestion so please take this in the spirit it's intended - your code would be vastly easier to read if you didn't cram it all into 1 line with minimal white space. Try running it through `gawk -o-` to see the difference in readability - I've had a fair amount of experience with awk and I had no idea what that one line of code does before doing that.

Comment: Now that I understand the code - if you use `ARGIND` instead of `FILENAME` as the 2nd index for `arr[]` then you can just loop from 1 to 3 (or hardcode those 3 numbers if you want to keep your existing code structure) without tightly coupling your code to the names of the input files, e.g. `arr[$1 OFS $2][ARGIND] = $3` and `print i, 1 in arr[i] ? arr[i][1] : "NA"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
FNR == 1 {
    if ( NR == 1 ) {
        numCols = split($0,hdrs)
    }
    else {
        hdrs[++numCols] = $3
    }
    next
}
{
    accsValsCols2ss[$1][$2][numCols] = $3
}
END {
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
        printf "%s%s", hdrs[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( acc in accsValsCols2ss ) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for ( val in accsValsCols2ss[acc] ) {
            printf "%s%s%s", acc, OFS, val
            for ( colNr=3; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
                s = ( colNr in accsValsCols2ss[acc][val] ? accsValsCols2ss[acc][val][colNr] : "NA" )
                printf "%s%s", OFS, s
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk S01.tsv S02.tsv S03.tsv
Accesion        Val     S01     S02     S03
AJ863320        1       0.2     NA      NA
AJ863320        2       NA      0.8     NA
AJ863320        5       NA      NA      0.2
AM930424        1       0.3     0.25    NA
AY664038        2       0.5     NA      NA
EU236327        1       NA      0.14    0.5
EU434346        2       NA      0.2     0.3
```

Comment: I really like the `FNR == 1` block here, collecting the return value (array.length) of `split()` and omitting a field separator argument to default to FS, compact and educational, my initial idea would have been unnecessarily complicated.